# Llenar una tabla con datos de una vista MySQL

Tags: mysql

Necesito llenar los datos de una tabla con los datos de una vista.

Ejemplo tengo una vista (view) que me muestra la suma(campo_1), suma(campo2) agrupados por (fecha_registro).

Es decir:

```
SELECT SUM(campo_1), SUM(camnpo_2) 
FROM tbale WHERE fecha_registro=fecha_registro GROUP fecha_registro;
```

Eso lo almaceno en una vista.

Pero tambien necesito almacenar esos datos en una otra tabla, donde se puedan modificar.

Como las vistas se actualizan automaticamente entonces, necesito que asi mismo se actualice los datos de la tabla. Que vienen siendo los mismos datos de la vista.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece entender que buscas algo así:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tabla_totales;
CREATE TABLE tabla_totales
SELECT * FROM totales;
```

Partiendo de este dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE ventas(
  id_venta int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  fecha date,
  cantidad int,
  precio float
  );

INSERT INTO ventas (fecha, cantidad, precio) VALUES
('2021-02-26',1,100),
('2021-02-26',3,120),
('2021-02-27',1,120),
('2021-02-27',1,100);
```

Y de esta vista:

```
CREATE VIEW totales AS
SELECT fecha,SUM(cantidad) cantidad,
  SUM(cantidad*precio) importe
  FROM ventas
  GROUP BY fecha;
```

Para que la tabla `tabla_totales` se actualice automáticamente, tendrías que eliminarla y volver a crearla, tal y como he indicado en el primer paso, dentro de un disparador que detecte cada modificación, inserción o borrado en la tabla `ventas`.

Efectivamente, la vista te facilita un poco las cosas, pero tampoco la necesitas si esa misma consulta de agrupamiento la incluyes en el disparador.

Lo que no termino de entender es para qué quieres modificar una tabla de resultados que se te va a ir actualizando con cada cambio de la tabla original. Perderías todos los cambios que realices.